# Getting IllegalArgumentException while creating custom Spring Data JPA query for nested object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create a custom Spring Data query which will find all training for a trainer between two dates.

Training class looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
public class Training extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "training", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "difficulty_level", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DifficultyLevel difficultyLevel;

  @Column(name = "completed")
  boolean completed;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = Training.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private TrainingParticipants trainingParticipants;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = Training.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private TrainingDate trainingDate;
}
```

with nested classes like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TrainingParticipants {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(targetEntity = TrainingParticipants.class)
  private User trainer;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = TrainingParticipants.class)
  private Set<User> trainee;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
class TrainingDate {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private LocalDateTime startDate;

  private LocalDateTime endDate;
}
```

AbstractBaseEntity for HashCodeEquals contract and @Version usage looks like:

```
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Version
  protected long version = 0;

  @JsonIgnore
  @Transient
  protected UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    AbstractBaseEntity that = (AbstractBaseEntity) o;
    return uuid.equals(that.getUuid());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return uuid.hashCode();
  }

  public AbstractBaseEntity(long version) {
    this.version = version;
  }

  public AbstractBaseEntity() {
  }
}
```

I created a Training repository with `JpaRepository` usage with method like:

```
@Repository
interface TrainingRepository extends JpaRepository<Training, Long> {

  List<Training> findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(
      Long trainerId,
      LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      LocalDateTime trainingEndDate);

  default List<Training> findAllTrainerTrainingsBetweenStartAndEndDate(
      Long trainerId,
      LocalDateTime trainingStartDate,
      LocalDateTime trainingEndDate) {

    return findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(
        trainerId, trainingStartDate, trainingEndDate);
  }
}
```

With IntelliJ hints, I created a custom query which will find out all training of trainer between two dates. Problem is that with the above approach I am receiving and an exception which looks like below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create the query for method public abstract java.util.List com.application.training.TrainingRepository.findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [trainer] on this ManagedType [com.application.common.AbstractBaseEntity]
```

I am a little bit confused because in the past when I was cooperating with IDE hints that were working properly. At the same time, I understand that I can use the classic SQL approach but in this scenario Spring Data is desirable. I will be grateful for a suggestions on how to fix a query and reach a goal.

EDIT:

for variant without `_` separator I have an error like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.appplication.training.TrainingRepository.findAllByTrainingParticipantsTrainerIdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [trainer] on this ManagedType [com.application.common.AbstractBaseEntity]
```

with separators it's looks like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.application.training.TrainingRepository.findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [trainer] on this ManagedType [com.application.common.AbstractBaseEntity]
```

EDIT 2: 
After suggestion @Simon Martinelli there is an error like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.application.training.TrainingRepository.findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual(java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
```

Comment: Why do you have _ in the method signature? Use Camel Case

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for your answer, it's used for a nested object in a class training. After removing it this is still not working.

Comment: Can you please update the Exception Message

Comment: @SimonMartinelli unfortunately, the error is the same while startup application.

Comment: Btu you get findAllByTrainingParticipants_Trainer_IdAndTrainingStartDateLessThanEqualAndTrainingEndDateGreaterThanEqual and I said remove the _ then it should be another message

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added two versions of error for separator and without it. It seems to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot navigate in a query over a ToMany relationship like trainingParticipants.

You have to join the two entities to have a alias for trainingParticipants. 
So you cannot use Spring Data JPA query methods for this query but have to create a JPQL query or a Specification.

```
@Query("select t from Training t join t.trainingParticipants p " +
       "where p.trainer id = :trainerId and t.trainingDate.startDate <= :trainingStartDate " +
       "and t.trainingDate.endDate <= :trainingEndDate")
List<Training> findTrainingOfTrainer(Long trainerId, LocalDateTime trainingStartDate, LocalDateTime trainingEndDate);
```

Comment: @Thank you so much for the answer. After ridding of a small typo p.trainerId and setting nativeQuery flag to true application starts without an error. I will check if the result of the query is proper as soon as possible. So far big + for you for a fast response.

Comment: No you don't have to set nativeQuery to ture. It's not a native Query!

Comment: thanks for the patience. Problem is that without this flag application is not starting. I posted an error as an edit part. I understand that is not a native query, I checked this flag only for a test purpose because today I have a pretty weird problem with syntax and hints in IntelliJ which is completely not understandable for me.

Comment: Try to use another name for the method like findTrainingFromTrainer